# Using filters to filter a variable value with GeoTools

Tags: features, geotools

I have a Java Swing application which loads a line shapefile and draws a map. I'm using a filter and a rule to filter out the lines in the shapefile where the attribute "traffic" is greater than 500. Each line has a different "traffic" value and this works perfectly ("traffic" means the maximum allowable traffic volume of the road). I can make a separate style for this filtered lines.

```
    Rule rule = sb.createRule(textSymbolizer);
    rule.setFilter(sb.getFilterFactory().greater(
            sb.getFilterFactory().property("traffic"), 
            sb.getFilterFactory().literal(500.0)));
    FeatureTypeStyle fts = sb.createFeatureTypeStyle("Feature",rule);
```

Now I want to do the following logic

```
if("traffic" property value > current_traffic_value){
    // style this line uniquely
}
```

The "current_traffic_value" is a integer value stored in a database for each line. So I want to check each line against a variable value. Can I achieve this using SLD methods? What would be the optimum method to achieve this?

Comment: I just found a quick method to accomplish this by using 'EnvFunction'. I first set a unique value 'EnvFunction.setGlobalValue(unique_str, variable_value);'. Then, I'd create a function as '    Function fn = ff.function("env", ff.property(unique_str), ff.literal(0));'. This fn can be easily used in 'rule.setfilter()'. I'm sure there are much better and clean ways to achieve this. The drawback here is that I have to set global value for each line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want then it should be a simple filter like:

```
Rule rule = sb.createRule(textSymbolizer);
rule.setFilter(sb.getFilterFactory().greater(
        sb.getFilterFactory().property("traffic"), 
        sb.getFilterFactory().property("current_trafic")));
FeatureTypeStyle fts = sb.createFeatureTypeStyle("Feature",rule);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Actually this is slightly different to what I need. I would need to get the "traffic" property (shapefile attribute) and test it against a value "current_traffic" which is stored in a database.

For example, there is a database where the current_traffic for each line is stored. And there is a "traffic" attribute in the shapefile attribute. I want to test these two values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best plan would be to put all the data in the database and create a view with the join.

Comment: Just for testing purposes I used 'EnvFunction'. For the next update I'd plan to put all data in a database. Then I believe I'd need to check and test both values and draw the line in the unique way manually on a line feature. Is that what you meant by "create a view with the join"?